# Spring Cloud Contract Consumer Test Issue

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am testing the consumer side of the spring cloud contract.

The provider is here: https://github.com/pkid/spring-cloud-contract-with-surefire.

The stubs jar generated from the provider is here: https://github.com/pkid/spring-cloud-contract-with-surefire-consumer/blob/master/sample-repo-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-stubs.jar

When I run the consumer test(source is here: https://github.com/pkid/spring-cloud-contract-with-surefire-consumer):

```
@Test
public void shouldGiveFreeSubscriptionForFriends() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/greeting")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"id\":1,\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}"));
}
```

When I do "mvn test", I can see that the stubs jar is correctly found and unpacked. However I got the error that the endpoint 2 "/greeting" does not exist(404).

Could you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `mockMvc` to connect to a WireMock instance. That won't work. Change `mockMvc` on the consumer side to a `restTemplate`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.sap.ngp.test:sample-repo-service:+:stubs:8080"}, workOffline = true)
public class ConsumerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldGiveFreeSubscriptionForFriends() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = new TestRestTemplate().exchange(RequestEntity
            .get(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/greeting"))
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build(), String.class);

        BDDAssertions.then(result.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(200);
        BDDAssertions.then(result.getBody()).isEqualTo("{\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}");
    }

}
```

Please read what mock mvc is for in the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

Comment: This really worked for me. Thanks a lot Marcin. Really appreciate. I used below versions
springCloud =2020.0.3
bootVersion=2.5.1
verifierVersion=3.0.3